# Constructing a sequence of simple functions which converges unif. to a bdd. meas. function $f$ on a meas. domain $E$

Tags: measure-theory

Suppose $f: E \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded measurable function defined on a measurable domain $E$.  Construct a sequence of simple functions which converges uniformly to $f$ on $E$.

All I know about my function $f$ is that it's bounded and measurable on $E$.  For a sequence to converge uniformly, I need to show that for each $\epsilon > 0$, there exists an index $N$, such that for all $n \geq N$, $|f_n - f| < \epsilon$.  I'm honestly not sure where to begin to actually start constructing this sequence.

As a side question, what if I was being asked to come up with a sequence of simple functions which converges pointwise to $f$ on $E$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $f_n(x) = {1 \over n} \lfloor n f(x) \rfloor$, then each $f_n$ is simple
and $|f_n(x) - f(x) | < {1 \over n}$.

For a visual, slice $\mathbb{R}$ into chunks $[k{1 \over n} , (k+1){1 \over n})$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @EricTowers: Thanks, still working on my typing skills...